# Video doesn't show on Android by QVideoWidget and QMediaPlayer (QT 5.2.1)

Tags: qt

I really need help here! :(

I am working on QT by deploying a small project to Android 4.0.3 (API 15). I use this code below to run a small video. I built it successfully and run by Desktop 5.2.1 MinGW 32bit, everything is fine! but when I deploy it to the emulator. the audio is fine but the video doesn’t show on and the screen is white ! I don’t know what the problem is.
I hope you can give me some advices. Thanks in advance.

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;

layout = new QVBoxLayout;
player = new QMediaPlayer;
QVideoWidget *vw = new QVideoWidget;

layout->addWidget(vw);
widget->setLayout(layout);

player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/sdcard/Music/video.mp4"));
player->setVideoOutput(vw);
widget->show();

vw->show();
player->play();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Qt Multimedia Widgets module is not supported on Android. That's an issue in Qt for Android. You can check it [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_Android_known_issues) that video display is only available using the VideoOutput and Video QML items.

Comment: yeah I see the problem now! could you suggest me another classes that I can use from QT?